# Asp.net wizard control active/current tab loses CSS effect on postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a wizard control which I have customized using Jquery and Css to look like this :

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

The blue one being the currect/active link/tab.

I tried using this:

.tab a:active
        {
             background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #EEEEEE;
            color: #FFF;
            cursor: default;
        }

But it shows the effect only as long as I keep the mouse key pressed. As soon as postback occurs it loses its effect, which makes sense but how do i make it stay?

Comment: You can create new class and assign it to the selected tab in code behind.

Comment: That did cross my mind, but I dont know how exactly its done?